# SWT Table Viewer add checkbox on row selection

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

In my table viewer, I want to add a checkbox to the last column when the user selects a row. How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you expecting the checkbox to remain after another row is selected, or no? Are you expecting that the last column is dedicated to these checkboxes, or would there be other data in that column as well?

Comment: @avojak hey thanks for the reply. Yeah, the last column is dedicated to the checkboxes and they should dissappear when a new selection is made

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a checkbox in a TableViewer of JFace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605677/how-can-i-create-a-checkbox-in-a-tableviewer-of-jface)

Comment: @Shashwat I already managed to create a checkbox in a table viewer when the table is created. what I want is to create them/make them visible only when a row is selected.

Comment: You can always use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` which gives you complete control of drawing the table cells.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik tables only have checkbox icon in the first column.

Additional icons/checkboxes would have to be drawn manually.

Another option is to insert controls manually into table items. E.g insert a composite with checkbox + text. An example of how to insert a control into a table can be found in:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet126.java